# How to render directive while binding InnerHTML in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

For example if I have data like this in `not-working.component.ts`

```
private _data: string = '<a routerLink="/not-working">click here to see it's not working</a>'
```

and in view `not-working.component.jade`:

```
div
  .wrapper([innerHtml]="_data")
```

so the result will be

```
div
  .wrapper
    a(routerLink="/not-working")
```

And the issue here is that routerLink is not rendered as a directive or angular component. Is it possible to render it as a component/directive?

Comment: I stumbled upon this problematic while trying to add dynamic components to the template. I think it's related. On the fly compilation has been removed from Angular 2 so we're left off with a Dynamic Component implementation. Take a look at these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: If you think it answers your question I suppose we could mark it as duplicate, or you could remove it. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it works ;)